# Можно ли использовать Razor Pages в модели MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Недавно начал изучать ASP.NET Core, делаю свой маленький проект. Вопрос. Можно ли использовать одновременно Razor Pages и модель MVC ?
Добавил шаблон регистрации и входа в профиль для сайта (Identity), а там все сделано с файлами .cshtml и к ним файлы .cs, и не очень понятно можно ли смешивать их с контроллерами. Или нужно написать саму форму регистрации и входа с использованием контроллеров? Наверное вопрос глупый, но повторюсь, только начал изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и нужно использовать,  потому что например, стандартная Идентификация с Microsoft.AspNet.Identity использует именно Razor Pages. Вот [здесь](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky) в репозитории рабочий код, для интернет-магазина на ASP.NET Core MVC для .NET 5, где идентификация и авторизация настраивается со стандартными и дополнительными представлениями, построенными на Razor-pages. Вот в этом [коммите](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky/commit/2f304be18cf710cbd3bad50f1a2f3d6f4249fc39), в файле StartUp.cs добавляется новая конечная точка,  и таким образом, в одном приложении используется маршрутизации и для Razor и для MVC.